# JqueryUI 1.8 and autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I have spent quite a few hours trying to get various autocomplete plugins to work with JQuery.

Then I found the following tutorial:
[How to Use the jQuery UI Autocomplete Widget](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-use-the-jquery-ui-autocomplete-widget/)

This tutorial is old and uses Jquery 1.4 and JQuery UI 1.8. How can I modify the Javascript code in it to be more JQuery2.0 and JQuery UI 1.10 compliant?

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(function(){  

    //attach autocomplete  
    $("#to").autocomplete({  

        //define callback to format results  
        source: function(req, add){  

            //pass request to server  
            $.getJSON("friends.php?callback=?", req, function(data) {  

                //create array for response objects  
                var suggestions = [];  

                //process response  
                $.each(data, function(i, val){                                
                suggestions.push(val.name);  
            });  

            //pass array to callback  
            add(suggestions);  
        });  
    },  

    //define select handler  
    select: function(e, ui) {  

        //create formatted friend  
        var friend = ui.item.value,  
            span = $("<span>").text(friend),  
            a = $("<a>").addClass("remove").attr({  
                href: "javascript:",  
                title: "Remove " + friend  
            }).text("x").appendTo(span);  

            //add friend to friend div  
            span.insertBefore("#to");  
        },  

        //define select handler  
        change: function() {  

            //prevent 'to' field being updated and correct position  
            $("#to").val("").css("top", 2);  
        }  
    });                       
});
```

There seem to be 3 problems with this:

1. One obvious error is the usage of .item which has been removed from JQuery UI-1.10.
2. When trying to use newer versions of both libraries, it leaves default text in the textbox. The default text comes from the JQuery-UI CSS and is something like "You have 2 results."
3. It seems to use JSONP. Is it possible to just accept JSON?

Any help with this would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Yep, just use JSON.

```
$('#someField').autocomplete({
      source: "friends.php?autocomplete=someField"
});
```

This will callback with an additional `term` parameter for the autocompletion; and expect an array of strings, or objects with `label` and `value` properties.

I've changed `callback` parameter-name to `autocomplete`, since you may have more than one of them;  and it's better to use meaningful & descriptive terminology.

See:  http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Autocomplete

Hope this helps.

Comment: But that still leaves a problem with number 1 and 2. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the deprecation is for the "internal data" stored by autocomplete;  not the `ui.item` property when handling the event. That's how I read it: http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#autocomplete

Comment: You can return 'false' from the `select()` function, if you don't want default behaviour. There's a lot of (undescribed purpose) logic in the example -- do you want a simple autocomplete, or all this fangly-dangly stuff with 'remove' links & stuff?

Comment: What I have spent hours trying to get at is something like SO's Tag Suggestion box with a body of information and a link. Remove tags would be great too. If you can help me get there, you have no idea how much that would mean to me.

Comment: Well, I could use the similar thing in the future! But at the moment I get by, by server-side parsing & suggesting "multiple items" expressions leading on from the items so-far & unmatched partial term.  Just try returning 'false' from select to stop the default behaviour, and see if it works.